# Erro ao tenta atualizar o visual Studio 2015 / Framework para versão 4.6.1

Tags: .net, framework, visual-studio-2015

Baixei o visual Studio 2015 e estava tudo certinho, mas infelizmente trabalho com uma maquina compartilhada e o outro usuário acabou deletando as instalações do .NETFramework 4.6.1 , agora estou tentando instalar novamente só que não aparecer no Visual Studio mais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -version 4.6.1
Tentando coletar informações de dependências do pacote 'EntityFramework.4.6.1' em relação ao projeto 'WebApplication1' visando '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Install-Package : O pacote 'EntityFramework' não foi encontrado nas seguintes fontes primárias: 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/'. Verifique se todas a
s suas fontes de pacote online estão disponíveis.
Em linha:1 caractere:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework -version 4.6.1
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

PM>

Sendo que já tenho o framework instalado na maquina.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente baixando o Pacote de Desenvolvimento:

https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=49978

Comment: Esqueci de falar, você pode está com o Framework instalado, mas pode não ser uma versão "compartilhada" com o VS.

Comment: E como tornaria uma versão não compartilha para versão compartilhada?

Comment: Você pode ter instalado um Framework que pertença ao SDK, tente por esse link https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=49981

Comment: Deu certo agora?

Comment: O Link resolve.